# error C2678: binary '>>' : no operator found which takes a left-hand operand of type 'std::istream'

Tags: compiler-errors

Help, please, to solve the problem. The error C2678: binary '>>' : no operator found which takes a left-hand operand of type 'std::istream' (or there is no acceptable conversion) appears in lines with cin

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;
struct Sales_data
{
  string ISBN;
  unsigned units_sold;
  double revenue;
};
int main ()
{
  Sales_data item;
  while (cin >> item)
  {
    cout << item << endl;
  }

  system ("pause");
  return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `Sales_data` is a custom struct that you have defined, thus by default there is no overload for `operator>>` and `operator<<` that takes your structure as an argument. You should implement these functions by yourself, it might look something like this:

```
std::istream& operator>>(std::istream& stream, Sales_data& data) {
    return stream >> data.ISBN >> data.units_sold >> data.revenue;
}

std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& stream, const Sales_data& data) {
    return stream << data.ISBN << data.units_sold << data.revenue;
}
```

Insert it between `Sales_data` declaration and `main` definition.